# Jquery ID apply

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create an dynamic order form using Jquery and PHP and got stuck. I have a Jquery code that `onclick` adds a new set of fields. Also in that jquery code I apply some style and jquery to one of the fields. Its an Multiselect, Searchable dropdown list.

Problem here however. I can apply this style so that it has the search bar etc. to the first one. the ones after are just random multilists with no vallues or searchbar.

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 100; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count

    //THIS WORKS!!
    var arrayFromPHP = ['foo', 'bar'];//<?php echo json_encode($a); ?>;
    $("#country" + x).select2({
        data: arrayFromPHP
    });

    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment

            //THIS DOESNT WORK!!
            var arrayFromPHP = ['foo', 'bar'];//<?php echo json_encode($a); ?>;
            $("#country" + x).select2({
                data: arrayFromPHP
            });

            $(wrapper).append('' +
                '<div>' +
                '<select id="country'+ x +'" multiple="multiple" style="width:300px;">' +
                '</select>' +
                '<a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div><input type="number" name="quantity'+ x +'" min="1" max="10"><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<div class="input_fields_wrap">
        <form method="post"><input type="submit" value="Add item" class="add_field_button"></form>
        <div>
            <select id="country1" multiple="multiple" style="width:300px;">
                <!-- Dropdown List Option -->
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So in the Jquery I put 2 comments in caps rage to mark what I mean that doesnt work.

Screenshots:

This on first sight

[image: This on first sight]

When I click in the multiselect tab this works.

[image: When I click in the multiselect tab this works.]

Picture speaks for itself. just messed up and if I click it nothing happends.

[image: picture speaks for itself. just messed up and if I click it nothing happends.]

Comment: There are multiple issues here... issues which are working together to cause a lot of headache. Fixing just one (changing `$(add_button).click` to `$(".add_field_button").click` ), isnt enough.

Comment: @IncredibleHat oke, I understand your point. but at least im trying. i changed that from your comment so thats 1 step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're initializing select2 before the HTML element exists:

```
$("#country" + x).select2({
  data: arrayFromPHP
});

$(wrapper).append('' +
  '<div>' +
  '<select id="country'+ x +'" multiple="multiple" style="width:300px;">' +
  '</select>' +
  'etc...');
```

The `select2` line should come **AFTER** you create the element with the `append` method.  Try this (note that I didn't copy the whole text: this is just illustrative):

```
$(wrapper).append('' +
  '<div>' +
  '<select id="country'+ x +'" multiple="multiple" style="width:300px;">' +
  '</select>' +
  'etc...');

$("#country" + x).select2({
  data: arrayFromPHP
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit Try this:

```
        var newContent = $('' +
            '<div>' +
            '<select id="country'+ x +'" multiple="multiple" style="width:300px;">' +
            '</select>' +
            '<a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div><input type="number" name="quantity'+ x +'" min="1" max="10"><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'
        )
        $(wrapper).append(newContent);
        newContent.find("#country" + x).select2({
            data: arrayFromPHP
        });
```

Comment: It doesnt fix my problem, but any reason this is better than the code I had? would like to know